# Button is getting enable only After entering text from keyword

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing one issue while doing automation where the button is getting enable only after entering text in the field
I need to click on CREATE Button after entering some text in the app name field. I have written code using JavaScript and it is entering value also but Button is not getting enable. The button is only getting enable when I am entering text using Keyboard.

Here is the code:

```
     JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
             Object appname =   jse.executeScript("return document.querySelector('body > sn-guided-app-creator').shadowRoot.querySelector('gac-focus-trap > gac-create-app-wizard').shadowRoot.querySelector('gac-wizard').shadowRoot.querySelector('gac-page-application-details').shadowRoot.querySelector('gac-page > section > form > div > div > gac-input.app-name-input').shadowRoot.querySelector('input');");
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value=''", appname);
```

Screenshot:
[Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UTq8.png)

This is serviceNow portal

Comment: that query selector looks absolute, can we have page url instead  ?

Comment: also you need to pass `arguments[0].value=''"` something in this. like `arguments[0].value='some name'`

Comment: @cruisepandey Element is in shadowDOM. So, I am using JS path for identifying. I can not share url because this is Office work. Meanwhile, I can tell that I am automating ServiceNow->Instance Create->Application Creation

Comment: I understand, but shadow root can be accessed via dynamic/relative selector.

Comment: @cruisepandey That I can modify later. Right Now, am the main issue is enabling CREATE Button while scripting entering text

Comment: did you pass try this `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value='some name here'";, appname);`

Comment: Yes, I have tried. it is entering data but Button is not getting enable. Button is only getting enable when I am manually entering same text from keyboard

Comment: okay are you using java ?

Comment: @cruisepandey yes,

Comment: okay I think you can try the below code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simulate keyboard strokes we have Actions class in Selenium.

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(appname).sendKeys("Your name").build().perform();
```